# Read file in C# Console Project works but not for App Project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin

Following these steps :

- *New Solution > Other > .NET > Console Project*
- *Project > Add Files > Path/to/myfile.txt*
- *myfile.txt > Build Action > EmbeddedResource*
- *myfile.txt > Quick Properties > Copy to Output Directory*

This is what `Program.cs` looks like :

```
namespace Program
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

This builds with no errors.

When I create, for example, an Android application (*New Solution > Android > App)* and repeat all the same steps as before, and try to build :

```
namespace Program
{
    [Activity(Label = "Program", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException has been thrown
>
> Could not find file "/myfile.txt"

Are there any other steps necessary to make sure the text file is available in the build process, for cross-platform application projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not behave the same way as a windows console app.  To achieve a similar function in Android, use an [Asset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=vswin)

Add the file to the Assets folder with a build action of *Android Asset*

```
// Read the contents of our asset
string content;
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader (assets.Open ("read_asset.txt")))
{
    content = sr.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I can use `string path = Foundation.NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("myfile", "txt", "Assets"); text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);` for the iOS side of things.

Comment: I knew it couldn't be that hard but I had to look high and low for 3 days to find this. Thank You!! I was doing this in the C# project so I had to change this line `AssetManager assets = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets;`